# Log into WiFi network on Android Wear

Tags: wi-fi, android-wear

Android Wear has a new feature where you can connect to WiFi and get notifications even while away from your phone.  If the WiFi network is secure, then it uses the login credentials last used on your phone. However, some WiFi networks aren't secure, but before you use the network, you must log in from a browser, such as at public places like cafes or hotels.

How can I do this from my watch, since these credentials are not saved for use on wear?

Comment: Since the login process isn't something the phone can "teach" the watch, you probably won't be able to use those networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limitation has been discussed in reviews, and is mentioned directly in Google's [Help page about it](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6207505?hl=en)

> **Note**: Your watch cannot connect to Wi-Fi networks that take you to a page before you can connect (for example, Wi-Fi networks at places like hotels or coffee shops).

It is simply not possible at this time with standard Android Wear.

XDA Developers does detail [a way](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android-wear/development/guide-connect-to-public-wifi-hospots-t3123995) that they claim works, **if rooted**, to achieve this, but it's a lot of extra steps, and won't work for devices such as the Moto 360 that don't give you access to ADB. Presumably custom ROMs could build something in to support this as well, but I've seen none at this time.